# In rails let the logged in user edit part of the database record for them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

In rails (with cancan or otherwise) I want the logged in user to be able to edit **some** of their database record but not all.

The database looks something like this:

```
User: name, password, team_id, role_id, notes
Role: name
Team: name
```

For instance, if the `current_user` (the one that is logged in) has a role of `user` then the only thing I want them to be able to do is change their own password. I don't want them to be able to rename themselves or change their team. I want managers to be able to add notes about themselves and other users but not other managers.

I am using a modified form of the following to do authentication:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

---

I was thinking of adding something like the following in `ability.rb`:

```
can :edit, User, :id => user.id
```

My questions are as follows:

1. How do I restrict the fields that I want them to have access to?
2. Where should this go, I was thinking in the controller not the model. (as I think stuff that deal with the current user permissions should not be in the model layer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something new you can take a look at, called [heimdallr](https://github.com/roundlake/heimdallr/), which pretty much seems to do what you require.
And here's [an article](http://borisstaal.com/post/20302867079/heimdallr-field-level-security-cancan-reinvented) with some info about it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - How do I restrict the fields that I want them to have access to?

Assuming that you have the above simple implementation, I would suggest to  to have a simple permission mechanism (Because I feel that CanCan is also restricting the user on editing / etc an entire record, not a part)

Your User model would be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def admin?
    role_id == 1
  end

end
```

and when showing the columns try to use a helper method to lock the textboxes, you may have a helper like

```
module UsersHelper
  def edit_name?
    current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

in your view

```
f.text_field :name, :readonly => edit_name?
```

Code is not perfect, but I think you get the idea!

> 2) user type selection (if the use is admin etc..) should go to model, because its belongs to domain login

But display/hide or active/inactive html elements are fallen in to presentation layer and better to use helper methods.

Comment: Wont the `:readonly` flag only affect the view. Such that if someone changed readonly to false in chrome developer console they would still be able to edit it.